# how to use count() in like mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    voucher_id,
    voucher_name,
    voucher_code,
    count(voucher_id)as counts
FROM  voucher_click_count 
WHERE 1   and 
      voucher_name LIKE '%1%'   
      OR voucher_code LIKE '%1%'   
      OR count LIKE '%1%'  
GROUP BY voucher_id   OR count LIKE '%1%'   
ORDER BY voucher_name DESC  
LIMIT 0 ,10
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there anything not working with the given query?

Comment: What error is being reported - it will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: There is no meaning to use count in group by like this `OR count LIKE '%1%'   `

Comment: What is your question? can you explain your full query

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
SELECT voucher_id, voucher_name, voucher_code, count(voucher_id)as counts 
FROM voucher_click_count 
WHERE 1   and voucher_name LIKE '%1%'  OR voucher_code LIKE '%1%' OR 
voucher_id LIKE '%1%'  
GROUP BY voucher_id 
ORDER BY voucher_name DESC LIMIT 0 ,10
```

`count` is a not field so use `voucher_id` instead of `count`